# where is the option for Active profile set in intelliJ?

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-14

where is the option for Active profile set in IntelliJ ?
How to set the application.property specifically using Active profile.?
Where to find the option for Active profile in IntelliJ on Windows OS.?

Answer (score 2):

I use `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`, and put it in the VM options.

To do this, you have to go to configurations—as in the image—and add the VM Options section.

[image: Add VM options profile dev]

After doing this, enter `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` in the box that appears to you.